# Zbar scan QRCode to open UIWebViewController?

Tags: ios

anyone knows is there any possible if I using Zbar to scan QRCode, it can open a WebViewController or UIViewController within my own iPhone App?

In my case, I'm developing a iPhone App which could collect 4 different company's info, by using build-in WebView or ImageView(not decide yet). When User Scaned 1st. company's QRCode, zbar needs to open that 1st. company's guide View......if Scan 2nd. QRCode...it opens 2nd. company's guide view.....etc.... any help would be appreciate!! sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 0):

The ZBar scanner just gives you back a value, and you can do whatever you choose with it.  See the following example, which pushes a WebViewController when a barcode is scanned.  You could modify it to check which barcode is scanned specifically, and load the right web view accordingly.

```
- (void) readerView: (ZBarReaderView*) view
     didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms
          fromImage: (UIImage*) img
{
    // do something useful with results
    for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) {

        NSString *data = sym.data;

        WebViewController *wv = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibNameAndURL:@"WebView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] url:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.companyname.com?scan=%@", data]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:wv animated:YES];

        break;
    }


}
```

Note that WebViewController is a ViewController which I created a custom initialization for so I could pass in a URL, and load it in the UIWebView once it's pushed to the Navigation Controller.

Hope that helps.